# How can I observe a specific moment in time in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I need to be notified exactly at midnight.(I will execute a piece of code but that's besides the point).

How would I set this up in RxSwift? Is there a built in feature that I missed, or is this actually just a standard case of PublishSubject, 
and deciding when (midnight happens) to call next() on it is out of scope of RxSwift?

Comment: Not sure how this task is related to Rx. Even waking up the app to perform a background task could be tricky. Can you elaborate on the idea? Perhaps do stuff in cloud while keeping a permanent subscription to it?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do this in a way that will be allowed on the app store. The closest you can come will be a scheduled local notification that fires at midnight, but that will display a message to the user, and only invoke your app if the user acknowledges the notification.